# List of the most frequently occurring words in the row

Tags: google-sheets, spreadsheet

I'm looking for a way to show (in the Google Spreadsheet) the most frequently occurring word in the row, but if it isn't one word I want to display all of them separated by semicolon which have the same count of occurrence.

**Explanation:**

For example, I want to fill the last column with values as below:

```
+---+------+------+------+------+------+-------------------+
|   |  A   |  B   |  C   |  D   |  E   |         F         |
+---+------+------+------+------+------+-------------------+
| 1 | Col1 | Col2 | Col3 | Col4 | Col5 | Expected response |
| 2 | A    | A    | C    | D    | E    | A                 |
| 3 | A    | A    | B    | B    | B    | B                 |
| 4 | A    | A    | B    | B    | E    | A, B              |
| 5 | A    | B    | C    | D    | E    | A, B, C, D, E     |
+---+------+------+------+------+------+-------------------+
```

Here's what I have achieved (formula for cell F2):

```
=INDEX(A2:E2; MODE(MATCH(A2:E2; A2:E2; 0)))
```

but it doesn't work for 4th and 5th row as I expect.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This works in Office 365 Excel, but probably will not in Excel online, as it is an array formula.

```
=TEXTJOIN(", ",TRUE,INDEX(A2:E2,,N(IF({1},MODE.MULT(IF(((MATCH(A2:E2,A2:E2,0)=COLUMN(A2:E2))*(COUNTIF(A2:E2,A2:E2)=MAX(COUNTIF(A2:E2,A2:E2)))),COLUMN(A2:E2)*{1;1}))))))
```

Being an array formula it needs to be confirmed with Ctrl-Shift-Enter instead of Enter when exiting edit mode.  If done correctly then Excel will put `{}` Around the formula.

[image]

---

EDIT:

To do it with Google Sheets as you now want:

```
=join(", ",filter(A2:E2,column(A2:E2)=match(A2:E2,A2:E2,0),countif(A2:E2,A2:E2)=max(countif(A2:E2,A2:E2))))
```

[image]

Comment: You're right, online excel doesn't recognize MODE.MULT. But it's a little closer to what I expect: except that it display only first occurrence from list of occurrences. In my previous formula I was receiving a "#N/A" for 5th row.

Comment: Did you use Ctrl-Shift-Enter when exiting edit mode?

Comment: This time yes, it surrounded itself by ArrayFormula(...) but it still doesn't recognize the MODE.MULT (in relation to online excel), so the result is one item. I think I have to investigate ArrayFormula command.

Comment: if it put `ArrayFormula` around the formula then you are not using Excel online.  You are using Google sheets and that is a totally different approach, and this question needs to have the tags stating such.

Comment: Thank you. I didn't know excel is so varied and complicated.

Comment: @user51390233 see edit for google sheets.  And remember that Google Sheets is not Excel.  The are two separate applications by two separate companies.

Comment: Thank you very much. It's works. I will remember for the rest of my life that exel is not Google Sheets and even differs to excel online.

Comment: Something strange is happening when I add empty column from the left side of input table. I'm getting Error: No matches are found in FILTER evaluation.

Comment: If I modified "column(A2:E2)" to "(column(A2:E2)- column(A2) + 1)", it start works.

Answer (score 0):

F2:

```
=JOIN(",",SORTN(TRANSPOSE(A2:E2),1,1,ARRAY_CONSTRAIN(FREQUENCY(MATCH(A2:E2,A2:E2,0),COLUMN(A2:E2)),COUNTA(A2:E2),1),0))
```

See syntax @ https://support.google.com/docs/table/25273

Comment: Thank you, it works as good as Scott Craner's response. Now, I have two solutions.